# MvxListView not displaying horizontally

Tags: android, mvvmcross

In my Android app I've created a vertical layout to hold a horizontal list of images (thumbnails) over top a larger view of a selected image from the list.  For some reason I cannot get the horizontal list to display horizontally it only appears as a vertical list.

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="15">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Mvx.MvxListView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Images"
                local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/image_item" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/BDSeal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10.0dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android, the system ListViews are vertical only.

There are open source horizontal list views available - eg cheesebaron once provided http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2012/12/horizontal-listview-for-mono-for-android.html - and I think this has been updated more recently.

Also some people use the PageAdapter to show this type of horizontally scrolling list.

Comment: Doh!  Makes sense I am a bit of an Android noob as if that wasn't apparent already.  Thanks